# Customizing WooCommerce product data label without plugin - WEIGHT

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, label, product

I'd like to change the product meta label from "Weight" to "Square Feet" in both the back end and front end.

I've tried this and a few [hundred] variations without success:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_register_post_type_product', 'custom_product_labels' );

function custom_product_labels( $args ) {
    //
    // change labels in $args['labels'] array
    //
    $args['labels']['_weight'] = 'Square Feet';
    return $args;
```

I've successfully edited the UNITs with this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_settings', 'add_woocommerce_dimension_units' );

function add_woocommerce_dimension_units( $settings ) {
  foreach ( $settings as &$setting ) {

    if ( $setting['id'] == 'woocommerce_dimension_unit' ) {

      $setting['options']['feet'] = __( 'ft' );  // foot
    }

    if ( $setting['id'] == 'woocommerce_weight_unit' ) {

      $setting['options']['sq ft'] = __( 'sq ft' );  // square feet
    }
  }

  return $settings;
}
```

But I still can't figure out how to hook into the measurement labels to edit them. **It's important to note** that I don't want to ADD a meta unit of "Square Feet" because we already have thousands of products filled in with the sq ft data in the Weight field.

My quick workaround was to find the actual code on these pages and edit them. But it's a poor solution.

woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-product-data-shipping.php

woocommerce/includes/wc-formatting-functions.php

woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php

Edit: Here is a page showing the use.
https://homedesigningservice.com/product/cape-house-plan-10034-cp/

Thank you in advance for saving my melting brain. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this snippet

```
    add_filter( 'gettext', 'theme_change_comment_field_names', 20, 3 );

function theme_change_comment_field_names( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

                switch ( $translated_text ) {

                    case 'Weight' :

                        $translated_text = __( 'Square Feet', $domain );
                        break;

                    case 'weight' :

                        $translated_text = __( 'Square Feet', $domain );
                        break;
                }


            return $translated_text; 
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Hm. That didn't work.

I don't think this would be an issue but I'm using WOOF Products Filter plugin. The only thing it affects (as far as I understand) is the label of the slider filter on the main shop page here: https://homedesigningservice.com/product-category/house-plans/

Comment: So I'm assuming there's some other plugin causing issues with this running properly. Any thoughts on how to begin that search?

Comment: If It is added static you can use string locator plugin to find 'weight'  word in theme or plugin

Comment: Change the priority then check

Comment: 20 replace with 99

Comment: I tested priority all the way down to 1 and it's still not working. 
So to be clear, this is what I have now, which isn't working:

add_filter( 'gettext', 'theme_change_comment_field_names', 1, 3 );

Comment: If you have any staging or developer portal then i can help with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206463/discussion-between-lakshman-rajput-and-heidi-denney).

Comment: I don't have a staging or developer portal setup but thank you so much for offering.

Comment: This worked once I closed my comment which was right above this and accidentally left open. smh Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Woo has a filter for front end but no filter for backend label changing.. So use below code and it won't conflict with any other label... Lakshman's gettext will change weight anywhere in the site...

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 
 'prefix_change_weight_label_to_square_feet', 10, 2 );

 function prefix_change_weight_label_to_square_feet( $product_attributes, $product ) {

   // Change Weight to Square Feet
   $product_attributes[ 'weight' ]['label'] = __('Square Feet');

   return $product_attributes;
}

// edit WEIGHT label to SQUARE FEET

add_action( 'admin_footer', function(){

   $currentPostType = get_post_type();

   if( $currentPostType != 'product' ) return;
?>
   <script>
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            if ( jQuery('label[for="_weight"]').length ) {

                jQuery('label[for="_weight"]').text("Square Feet");
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>

 <?php

});
```

Comment: I guess it does not work for Order page and order invoices 

Comment: if needed... can be changed via filters.... we have filters for that too...